# prawcore.exceptions.NotFound: received 404 HTTP response

Tags: http-status-code-404, praw

Hey guys I'm having trouble figuring this out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SOLIS.py", line 62, in <module>
    com_df1 = scraper.comments(sub_id_list,keywords1,keywords2)
  File "/Users/CarranzaEE/Desktop/CDS 491:DEXIS/Reddit_SOLIS/Reddit_SOLIS.py", line 252, in comments
    if((comment.author is None) or (hasattr(comment.author, 'id') != True)):
  File "/Users/CarranzaEE/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/base.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    self._fetch()
  File "/Users/CarranzaEE/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/redditor.py", line 171, in _fetch
    data = self._fetch_data()
  File "/Users/CarranzaEE/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/redditor.py", line 168, in _fetch_data
    return self._reddit.request("GET", path, params)
  File "/Users/CarranzaEE/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 765, in request
    json=json,
  File "/Users/CarranzaEE/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 339, in request
    url=url,
  File "/Users/CarranzaEE/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 265, in _request_with_retries
    raise self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS[response.status_code](response)
prawcore.exceptions.NotFound: received 404 HTTP response
```

This error happens when I try to use author (an instance of Redditor) to try and call author.id. PRAW documents also say that Shadowbanned accounts are treated the same as non-existent accounts, meaning that they will not have any attributes, and that will only return name and is_suspended.

But is_suspended is no longer an attribute provided by reddit api. So I'm having trouble trying to handle cases where the account is a shawdowbanned account. Any tips or ideas?